# How to capture specific fields while making a Facebook CURL request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm trying to make a request to get only the email (or any other specific field) like it's done in the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ but using CURL

Using
`curl -X GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`
returns
`{"name":"SOME NAME","id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}`

Using
`curl -X GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=email`
returns the same output

How can I use CURL to get `{"email":"email@domain.sth"}` ?

---

Note: Using
`curl -X GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?fields=email&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`
returns
`{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"FBTRACE_ID"}}`

Comment: well, use a valid access token then. and of course it has to include the email permission.

Comment: I'm using the same access token for the three requests with the email permission granted. Only the third case (when the access_token parameter is sent second) gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

& is used to fork process. So in order for it to work, you need to quote your URL "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?fields=email&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN". So your command would look like `curl "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me?fields=email&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"`